# Comparar 2 variáveis em um select com Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, html-option

Olá, eu tenho um array de objetos que estou puxando do banco de dados e jogando em um Select HTML, só que eu também estou passando uma outra variável e gostaria de comparar essa variável com os valores do array do BD e caso forem iguais definir como selected a opção. Estou usando angular. Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 input_formulario" ng-init="vm.tipoSeguro()">
    <select name="setor_destino" required="" ng-model="user.tipoSeguro" >
        <option value="">Nome do seguro</option>
        <option ng-repeat="seguros in vm.mostraTipoSeguro track by seguros.id" value="{{seguros.nome}}">{{seguros.nome}}</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

O ng-model que tenho ali no select é para enviar o valor selecionado para a função no controller que envia o formulário por e-mail.

Segue HTML feito com a resposta Gabriel Câmara:

```
<select name="setor_destino" required="" ng-model="user.tipoSeguro" >
    <option value="">Nome do seguro</option>
    <option ng-repeat="seguros in vm.mostraTipoSeguro track by seguros.id" value="{{seguros.nome}}" ng-selected="seguros.id == vm.cookie">{{seguros.nome}}</option> 
</select>
```

E o meu controller:

```
vm.tipoSeguro = function () {
    SimulacaoService.listaTipoSeguro().then(function (response) {
        if (response.data != 0) {
            vm.mostraTipoSeguro = response.data;
            vm.cookie = $.cookie("nome_seguro");
            $.removeCookie("nome_seguro");
        } else {
            vm.mostraTipoSeguro = '';
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Tenta fazer um forEach no controller e monta uma nova lista, dá pra vc criar um novo atributo `checked` nessa nova lista, e todos que forem iguais tem esse valor true, e o restante tem o valor false

Comment: Uma outra repetição traria problemas de performance, já que o angular verifica todas as variáveis no ciclo de $digest, imagine se o valor de alguma dos elementos dentro da estrutura `mostraTipoSeguro` sofresse uma alteração, isso faria com que no próximo ciclo todos os watchers fossem ativados e esses disparariam mais watchers até que não houvesse mais mudanças. Agora dentro de cada ciclo desse, havaria um outro `forEach` sendo executado. Pra uma aplicação pequena talvez o custo nao seja alto e quase nao se perceba, mas em uma aplicação grande faria diferença, especialmente em celulares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o select fique selecionado é necessário que o model tenha o mesmo valor que o value, dessa forma o angular automaticamente identificará que os valores são iguais e a opção ficará selecionada por padrão.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode fazer isso utilizando a diretiva ngSelected. 
Nesse [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfxn7s9k/2/) eu criei um exemplo para você verificar

### Edição

Fiz um ajuste com o módulo ngCookies do AngularJS. 
Imagino que quando você atribui o `$.cookies`, é um objeto do jQuery, nesse caso você estaria apontando para a referência e, não sei o que o jQuery faz por debaixo dos panos quando adiciona/remove/altera um cookie, mas esse pode ser o motivo, pois você depois de atribuir o valor, remove o cookie.

Comment: Olá, eu fiz exatamente como você mostrou, mas para mim não mostra o selected, irei editar a minha pergunta para mostrar como fiz.

Comment: Favor ver a edição. Alterei o link do JSFiddle

Comment: Eu não estou utilizando cookies do angular, estou usando cookies o jquery cookies mesmo. No meu caso, eu salvo o cookie em uma variável antes de excluir ele, e consigo imprimir esse cookie na tela, só não consigo fazer a verificação.

Comment: Esse cookie retorna como uma String ou como um inteiro?

Comment: eu coloquei pra retornar um inteiro, no caso o ID do seguro, mas posso colocar para retornar o nome, tanto faz

Comment: Hum, pode ser que no momento que você receba a resposta da promise, o seu escopo não seja atualizado, já que é assíncrono. Pode, por favor, tentar aplicar um `$apply` depois da linha `vm.cookie = $.cookie...`

Comment: eu nunca usei esse apply, mas seria assim, que se usa ele: vm.cookie = $.cookie("nome_seguro");  vm.$apply(); ? pois está dando erro, dizendo que não é uma função

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e me parece que não é esse o problema. O `$apply` é uma função do escopo `($scope ou $rootScope)`. Ele serve para indicar ao Angular que alguma coisa foi alterada fora do escopo. Um exemplo seria se você utilizasse um `setTimeout` ou uma função nativa do javascript, que acabaria alterando uma variável e o Angular nao saberia.

Comment: Talvez seja por que eu não estou usando o controller principal? eu estou usando o controler de outro módulo

Comment: Mas a questão é que eu consigo enviar o valor pro HTML, então eu acredito que o problema seja na forma em que o select está sendo feito

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39226/discussion-between-gabriel-camara-and-bernardo-kowacic).